# Typescript Type for routeNameRef in React Navigation v5 in screen tracking for analytics

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, firebase-analytics

I am following the docs to implement screen tracking with `react-native-firebase` analytics in a React Native App that uses Typescript. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/screen-tracking and https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/screen-tracking

I found the type for navigationRef:

```
import { NavigationContainer, NavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';
const navigationRef = useRef<NavigationContainerRef>(null);
```

But I cannot find the type for routeNameRef and I am getting some linting errors if I hover over `navigationRef.current?.getCurrentRoute().name`:

```
Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
const navigationRef: React.RefObject<NavigationContainerRef>
```

Here is my code:

```
const Navigator = () => {
  const navigationRef = useRef<NavigationContainerRef>(null);
  const routeNameRef = useRef();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
    ref={navigationRef}
    onReady={() => {
      routeNameRef.current = navigationRef.current?.getCurrentRoute().name;
    }}
    onStateChange={async () => {
      const previousRouteName = routeNameRef.current;
      const currentRouteName = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name;

      if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
        await analytics().logScreenView({
          screen_name: currentRouteName,
          screen_class: currentRouteName,
        });
      }
      routeNameRef.current = currentRouteName;
    }}
```

What is the proper type for routeNameRef?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to define the ref's type:

```
const routeNameRef = useRef<String>();
```

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me in typescript...

```
       import { NavigationContainer, NavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';
       import analytics from '@react-native-firebase/analytics';
      ...

        const navigationRef = React.useRef<NavigationContainerRef>(null);
        const routeNameRef = React.useRef<NavigationContainerRef | any>(null);
```

....

```
       <NavigationContainer
        ref={navigationRef}
        onReady={() =>
        (routeNameRef.current = navigationRef.current?.getCurrentRoute()?.name)
      }
      onStateChange={async () => {
        const previousRouteName = routeNameRef.current;
        const currentRouteName = 
      navigationRef.current?.getCurrentRoute()?.name;

        if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
          await analytics().logScreenView({
            screen_name: currentRouteName,
            screen_class: currentRouteName,
          });
        }

        // Save the current route name for later comparison
        routeNameRef.current = currentRouteName;
      }}
    >
```